# Java byte to short convert randomly attached 0xff problem

Tags: java

I am trying to cast from byte to short, but the value is randomly attached to 0xff. Is there a way to handle it normally?

```
short[] shortArray = new short[size];

for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    shortArray[index] = (short) byteArray[index];
```

Comment: "but the value is randomly attached to 0xff" what does this mean?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: It is literally Some values ​​are normally cast to the same value as byte, but some values ​​are prefixed with 0xff (eg, 0xff10).

Comment: `0xff10` is not plausible ... but `0xff90` is.  Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  with a clear / precise example of what you are seeing and what you are expecting to see.  I / see suspect that the real problem is that you are not understanding how 2's complement number representations work.  But a minrep will help us to distinguish that from ... something else.

Comment: FWIW: I don't think that "random" is an accurate description of the behavior here.

Answer (score 2):

The negative numbers always must have **1** in leftmost bit.
If **byte** array has negative numbers, their representation in **short** format requires left byte to be **0xff** to keep the same negative value.

For example:

- the decimal **byte** value **-2** is binary **0b1111_1110** or hexadecimal **0xfe**
- the decimal **short** value **-2** is binary **0b1111_1111_1111_1110** or hexadecimal **0xfffe**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to do an unsigned conversion (e.g. got results in range [0..255]).

`byte` is a signed type in Java, so converting negative `byte` values to `short` will produce negative numbers (and in two's complement system you'll see 0xff prefix).

Bit representation, however, is same for signed and unsigned bytes, for example `(byte) 0xFF` means 255 as unsigned, but is -1 if treated as signed one.

Unsigned conversion can be done by implicit promotion to int, picking 8 low bits using AND  and downcasting result to short:

`shortArray[index] = (short) (byteArray[index] & 0xFF);`